# String Search Replace AS3

Tags: css, actionscript-3, string, actionscript, replace

I have a bit of text

"this is the text want I want to do is replace the text, I have just added another is for good measure"

This is stored as a standard string but I want to turn this into html and add css classes like, in this example wrapping around the word "is";

"this is the text want I want to do 
is replace the text, I have just added another is for good measure"

Any ideas how I can do this in as3?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be to use String.replace().  Like this:

```
var html:String = "This is a test";
html.replace(/is/g, "<b>is</b>");
```

You will probably want to get a little more advanced than that (notice the problem with case) See the Flex documentation on it here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=09_Working_with_Strings_09.html

Comment: Ended up using RegExp but your looks a bit neater.

Thanks.